# Save a ordering list of data into core data

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, tableview

i have an nstableview, where the user can add rows.
each row will directly save into Core data.

at the moment i can request the records of core data and sort it by objects id to get the correct order, because the object id is nearly the same like an incremental number.

but now the user can reorder the rows.
how can i save this new order of rows into core data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the id as a way to order is not guaranteed to work, so you shouldn't do that.

Instead, add a field that represents the order.

What we do is have a field called `pos` that is in integer and we set it sparsely. The first record can be 100, the second 200, etc.  Then when we re-order, we set pos to the mid-point of the records right before and after.  Every once in a while, you need to re-number the records.  The more sparse you do it, the less you need to re-number.

When you add a new record set it to the max value + 100 (or whatever spacing you are using)

Comment: The largest number you need to store is the expected max # of records * 100.  So, pick accordingly (32 is probably fine).